# What is the difference between Loopback Interface and Dummy Interface in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, networking, loopback

I would like to know whats the differences between loopback and dummy interfaces in Ubuntu and how they behave.

Because when I assign /24 IP address on Loopback interface and route this range in my network, the server responds to all IP addresses even to those ip addresses which is not assigned to the interface. But dummy interface behave like physical interface and responds to specific IP address which I've assigned to the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to other interfaces, when the Linux kernel adds an address to the loopback interface, its LAN route as also added as type `local` and `scope host` (these are what matter) to the *local* routing table (this is what makes it harder to find), instead of the *main* routing table.

To check the difference, check all routing tables entries (`table all`) that were added by the kernel (`proto kernel`) and are of type `local`.

From a system with only `lo` up and nothing else done:

```shell
# ip route show proto kernel type local table all
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local scope host src 127.0.0.1 
#
```

Here all addresses in the range 127.0.0.0/8 belong to the host (`scope host`).

Create `dummy0` and an address on it:

```shell
# ip link add name dummy0 up type dummy
# ip addr add 192.0.2.2/24 dev dummy0

# ip route show proto kernel type local table all
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 192.0.2.2 dev dummy0 table local scope host src 192.0.2.2 
# ip route
192.0.2.0/24 dev dummy0 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.2.2 
#
```

Instead add it on `lo`

```shell
# ip addr flush dev dummy0
# ip addr add 192.0.2.2/24 dev lo

# ip route show proto kernel type local table all
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 192.0.2.0/24 dev lo table local scope host src 192.0.2.2 
local 192.0.2.2 dev lo table local scope host src 192.0.2.2 
# ip route
#
```

This time 192.0.2.0/24 is of `scope host`, making the whole range belong to the host just as 127.0.0.0/8, instead of only 192.0.2.2 (/32) in the previous results. Linux following the Weak [Host Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model), will answer for these addresses for requests made on any interface, including ARP requests when relevant.

---

There are multiple ways to obtain the same results. So what can or should be used depends on the goal to achieve. *pro* and *con* below aren't always pro and con, but that's to compare them.

- `dummy0`

  - pro (for something else than *dummy*)

    - if routing/forwarding is enabled, the kernel, having by default added an automatic (`proto kernel`) LAN route will route received packets to this interface if not its own address. Doesn't make much sense for a *dummy* interface though, since traffic will be discarded. Yet using a *dummy* interface could be one way to blackhole a route (one other more permanent way being to add a route of type `blackhole` which doesn't rely on an interface).
  - con

    - one address. Multiple commands/operations are needed to add multiple addresses, one per command.
- `lo`

  - pro

    - add a whole range of host addresses in one swoop

      This should be reserved to projects related to intercepting traffic on  a large scale. Note that what matters is the route added by the kernel, not the address itself. Such route is used for example by [Linux' tproxy](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/tproxy.rst?h=v6.6#n33) for transparent proxying:

      > ```
      > # ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
      > # ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
      > ```

      but with specific policy-routing rules in place so it doesn't *always* apply.

      Outside of this, just add /32 addresses when using `lo` if it's ever done.
    - permanent interface, neutral role

      This interface is guaranteed to exist, so can be used as an anchor to add addresses in advance without knowing what interface will exist or should be used. The routes related to this address won't change when an interface goes down, since it's on `lo` (which has no reason to go down). Some routing daemons might handle in a special way addresses added on the loopback interface.
  - con

    - cannot be used for static routing/forwarding

      Routes added for the `lo` interface are not meant to route elsewhere: the target is the host.

Comment: How can I configure this for dummy interface: pro (for something else than dummy)

Comment: @MesbahAhmadi can you be more specific? I did answer your question. But you don't provide any information on *why* you're asking your question. Beware of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). If you have a **reasonable** additional request in your question, please edit your question and add it there. Else consider if my answer answered your question or not: if so, ponder accepting my answer, if not: explain why not.

Comment: You explain very clear and it is useful. But I want to know how can I configure dummy interface as act like loopback Interface. Is there any way ?

Comment: I don't see where you're going at but you can add manually the routes yourself instead of letting the kernel do it. `ip addr add 192.0.2.2/24 dev dummy0 noprefixroute; ip route add local 192.0.2.0/24 dev dummy0`